# Why is Heap dump created larger than the max heap assigned after tomcat crash

Tags: java, tomcat, heap-dump

In java_opts I have set Max Heap to 2.5gb ( -Xms1024m -Xmx2560m ) but the Heap dump created after tomcat crash is of 4gb. I have been noticing it from some time. Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: which java version it is? what is the size of permgen?

Comment: The heap dump contains more than just the heap. It would also contain thread states and stacks, and some information about the fault.

Comment: java version is **1.6** and size of prem gen is **256m**